# What is the shortest 1:16 mutual stalemate with the White king at home?

Tags: problems, records, stalemate

In [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/2thz06/stalemate_puzzle/) ancient r/chess thread, several users explored the shortest possible 1:16 mutual stalemate. StoofBuzze provided a record in 42.5 moves. However, what is the shortest such game in which the White king is at home, aka e1, in the final position? Below is my work.

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 5/8/2021, Non-Unique Proof Game In 48.0 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. a4 b5 2. b3 e5 3. Ra2 Qg5 4. d3 Qxc1 5. Nh3 Nc6 6. Ng1 Nd4 7. g3 Nf6 8. Bg2 Ne4 9. c4 Nc2+ 10. Kf1 Na1 11. Ke1 Nd2 12. Bf1 Nxb1 13. Bg2 d5 14. e4 Bg4 15. Bf1 Bxd1 16. Re2 bxa4 17. Re3 Ba3 18. Rf3 Bb2 19. g4 Kd7 20. Re3 Kc6 21. Rf3 Kc5 22. Re3 Kb4 23. Rf3 Ka3 24. Re3 Ka2 25. b4 c5 26. Rg3 cxb4 27. d4 exd4 28. Rc3 f5 29. f4 fxe4 30. Bg2 g5 31. Bf1 gxf4 32. Bg2 h5 33. Bf1 hxg4 34. Rc2 Rxh2 35. Bd3 Rxc2 36. Bf1 Rh8 37. Bd3 Rhh2 38. Bf1 Rhd2 39. Nf3 gxf3 40. Be2 fxe2 41. Rh3 a5 42. Re3 a3 43. Rf3 a4 44. Rh3 b3 45. Rg3 dxc4 46. Rh3 c3 47. Rg3 d3 48. Re3 fxe3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question. Here's a slight variant of your construction that saves two moves.

```
[Title "Proof Game In 46.0 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. a3 Nc6 2. Ra2 Na5 3. Ra1 Nb3 4. Ra2 Na1 5. Nh3 Nf6 6. Ng5 Nd5 7. Nc3 e5 8. Nb5 Nc3 9. Nd4 Nb1 10. Nf5 d5 11. Nh3 Qg5 12. d4 Qxc1 13. Nf4 c5 14. Nh5 cxd4 15. Rg1 Kd7 16. Rh1 Kc6 17. Rg1 Kb5 18. Rh1 Ka4 19. Nh4 Bg4 20. Rg1 Rc8 21. Rh1 Rxc2 22. Rg1 Kb3 23. e4 Kxa2 24. b3 a5 25. Rh1 a4 26. Rg1 axb3 27. a4 b5 28. a5 Ba3 29. Nf5 Bb2 30. Nd6 b4 31. Nb5 f5 32. Na3 bxa3 33. a6 fxe4 34. a7 Bxd1 35. a8=Q g5 36. Nf4 gxf4 37. Bc4 dxc4 38. Qa7 d3 39. Qe3 fxe3 40. f3 h5 41. g4 hxg4 42. Rg2 Rxh2 43. Rg3 Rhd2 44. Rg2 c3 45. Rf2 gxf3 46. Re2 fxe2
```

Comment: If I counted right, Black needs 46 moves anyway, so with this final position, it is optimal. Critical are the pawn moves. Thus I suggest trying Kd1 Pd2...d6 (the rest is nearly unique!), where I count 44 moves if Black doesn't waste a move.